# Test docker containers using travis-ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, travis-ci, dockerfile

I have created a development environment with docker. This dev environment includes ubuntu 14.04 container (installed apache and node dependencies) , mysql container (official image) and a phpmyadmin container. How can I ensure that all containers are working fine and all dependency software installed in relevant containers using Travis-CI ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any test tool that can use to test docker containers. But in order to test whether docker containers are up and running, I wrote some CLI command test cases (functional tests) using a testing framework. I suggest you to try [codeception](http://codeception.com/) PHP testing framework which is built by extending [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/). And it is very easy to write shell command test cases using codeception framework.

we can simply automate the codeception test cases in travis-ci